# Wpf design ; multiple views in one window

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

Im building an application where I want to head for a design, that could remind of a dockpanel.

What I want, is having buttons in the left side (or left panel) representing different areas of the application (e.g "Milk", "Bread") and then have different "views" in the middle-panel.

What I already have tried, is making an application with a "Frontpage", and buttons changing the whole window/usercontrol - this however will not give me static areas/panels.

I do not want to use a tabcontrol with the tabtitemstrip being vertical - however it is kinda the same functionality im looking to have.

Any ideas?

Below is a picture with the wished design, to kinda give an idea of my thoughts.. Any help appreciated :)

http://s57.photobucket.com/user/RolleKn/media/wpfdesign_zps3737b014.jpg.html

Comment: What are you actually asking? What are you having a problem with? You could lay this out very easily using a dock panel but as you have already mentioned it I presume you mean something else?

Comment: Oh, right. My question is: What kind of container should I use for holding these different "views/pages"?. I mean - for example I could have different grids on top of each other, and then making the respective grid visible /hidden depending on which button i press

Comment: @rollekn Have a look at the Prism library and how you can create composite user interfaces for WPF in an MVVM way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use WPF, use `ContainerControl` or `ContentPresenter` for that.

In general, "switching Visibility On/Off" is not a good way to go. It forces the UI to create all objects, even those invisible ones, and to handle their data and events, etc.

And you need to switch it all manually.

WPF provides you with many mechanisms that can save you this. Some are smarter than others, some not.

One of the **most basic** mechanism in WPF is the `Control` and its `Template` property. You can replace whole your Grid+Contents+SwitchingVisibility idea with a single `Control` and switching its `Template`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="panel1"> ..carrots.. </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="panel2"> ..cucubers.. </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="panel3"> ..donkey.. </ControlTemplate>
    ...
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Control x:Name="foo" />
</Grid>
```

Now, if you get the `foo` and set its `.Template` and set it to `panel1`, then the "carrots" will show up. if you set it to `panel3`, donkeys. And so on.

It's very powerful, but it will not be really handy due to some other things I won't cover. There are books and tutorials that explain Templates in depth. Also, this mechanism **is really not designed for such task**. It's the most basic one, and a good thing to know if you want to work in WPF, but there are more suitable ones here.

Second next powerful and still basic mechanism is `ContentControl/ContentPresenter`. They work almost in the same way (actually CC uses CP internally), so I'll skip it.

ContentControl is a smart control that knows how to **automatically** select a correct **Template** with respect to the data you are tryng to present.

So:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="CarrotData"> ..carrots.. </..>
    <DataTemplate DataType="CucumberData"> ..cucubers.. </..>
    <DataTemplate DataType="DonkeyData"> ..donkey.. </..>
    ...
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ContentControl x:Name="foo" Content="{Binding ..}" />
</Grid>
```

Note the change from 'ControlTemplate' to 'DataTemplate'.
Now, with this setting, you don't even need to switch templates manually. You just get the "foo" and set its Content to either:

- a CarrotData object, that contains the carrot-related data
- a CucumberData object, that contains the cucumber-related data
- a DonkeyData object, that contains the donkey-related data

Once you set the data to be shown (i.e. `foo.Content = carrots[5]`), the ContentControl will pick the relevant template to be shown.

You can **bind** the `Content` property to just about anything. If you have some dataclass that contains carrots/donkeys and has a property `CurrentThing`, you can bind to it and ContentControll will switch the views automatically along with the changes to CurrentThing.

That's basics. There's much more to it, in almost any point I tried to briefly cover. For now, leave ControlTemplates. Read about DataTemplates and Bindings. Read about ContentPresenter (shows 1 template for 1 item) and ItemsControl (shows N items+templates). Then, read a little on MVVM pattern.

You will quickly see that "having everything in one Grid" and "switching Visibility" is an odd way to do it.

However, I wouldn't be fair if I didn't mention that everything has a cost included. Extensive use of templates and bindings makes your app a bit slower compared to what you could get when you do everything manually. But usually, doing it manually is just not really worth it.